# Why does inherting from object in Python, change they type of the __dict__ when not specifying a parent does not?

Tags: python, inheritance

I have a simple piece of code that tries to give a convenience to `file` in Python.

```
class File:
    def __init__(this, *args):
        this._file = file(*args)

    def __del__(this):
        this._file.close()

def createCallForwarder(method):
    return lambda obj,*args: method(obj._file, *args)

_dict = file.__dict__
for (k,v) in zip(_dict.keys(), _dict.values()):
    if not (k.startswith('__') and k.endswith('__')):
        if v.__class__.__name__ == 'method_descriptor':
            File.__dict__[k] = createCallForwarder(v)

# get the repr method
File.__repr__ = createCallForwarder(dict_proxy['__repr__'])
```

If i change `File` to inherit from `object`, it does not let me assign the methods.

Why is it different?

Comment: What in heavens name are you trying to achieve with your code? Why not use a subclass of `file`, or use a `__getattr__` hook to proxy methods?

Comment: Use `setattr` if you want to do the same thing in new style classes: `setattr(File, k, createCallForwarder(v))`

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I needed. I dont have that much experience with Python. I was just trying to get a File object that closes itself so I don't have to care. I don't want to leak file objects.

Comment: Just a style tip: Python, by convention, uses `self` instead of `this`.

Comment: And don't use `this` in python, Python's convention is to use `self`.

Comment: @AadityaKalsi: Python file objects **already do that**. They **have** a `__del__` handler of their own.

Comment: And at the same time, relying on an object's finalizer (your own or the built-in `file`) to clean up resources is a really bad idea. It *mostly* works in *most* circumstances on CPython. But as soon as you get used to not cleaning up explicitly, the files get caught up in reference cycles or your code is run in a different Python implementations, and once that happens you're screwed because you have a thousand leaks and no experience with preventing them. Just use a `with` statement, it's just a matter of habit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not be accessing `__dict__` directly at all.

Use a [`__getattr__` method](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__) to proxy calls to the underlying `self._file` object instead:

```
class File(object):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self._file = open(*args)

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self._file, name)
```

I've also switched the code to best-practices; using `self` instead of `this` and using `open()` instead of `file()`.

For new-style objects (inheriting from `object`), use [`setattr()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr) to set arbitrary attributes. There is no need to use a call forwarder wrapper, however. You could have taken the *bound* methods of `self._file` and set those directly on `self` too:

```
class File(object):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self._file = open(*args)
        for name in dir(self._file):
            setattr(self, name, getattr(self._file, name))
```

If all you wanted was a file object that auto-closes on garbage collection, then you went through a lot of trouble for nothing. Python file objects *already* have a `__del__` handler that does *exactly that*. It is just not exposed as an explicit `__del__` function, instead the C implementation uses a [deallocation function](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/b0866382064f/Objects/fileobject.c#l613) that calls `close_the_file(f)` when deallocated.

Best practice, however, is to use file objects as context manager, using the [`with` statement](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement):

```
with open(somefilename) as fileobj:
    # do all sorts with fileobj

# here, fileobj will have been closed automatically.
```

Quoting from the [`file.close()` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects):

> As of Python 2.5, you can avoid having to call this method explicitly if you use the with statement. For example, the following code will automatically close *f* when the `with` block is exited:
>
> ```
> from __future__ import with_statement # This isn't required in Python 2.6
>
> with open("hello.txt") as f:
>     for line in f:
>         print line,
> ```

Comment: Thanks! That was very helpful and I prefer the __getattr__ way.

The only lil problem I have is that it doesn't play well with readline for auto completion.

The reason I have this implementation is because I have other objects who may be writing to the same file multiple times, and to <code> open </code> multiple times is costly.

Comment: @AadityaKalsi: Proxying the file object doesn't buy you *anything* in that case. File objects already auto-close in CPython.

Comment: @AadityaKalsi: You can implement a [`__dir__` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir) perhaps to help with autocompletion.

Answer (score 0):

> I was just trying to get a File object that closes itself

Use a [`with statement`](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm) which will (among other things), close files for you:

```
with open('somefile.txt') as the_file:
   for line in the_file:
      # do something with line

# Once outside the with block, the file is automatically closed
print('somefile.txt is closed here')
```